# Get click form ScrollGallery Image Flutter

Tags: dart, package, flutter

I am trying to implement flutter scrollGallery in my app like this.

```
ScrollGallery(
              <ImageProvider>[
                AssetImage('images/y1.jpg'),
                AssetImage('images/z3.jpg'),
                AssetImage('images/z7.jpg'),
              ],
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
```

But i need click from large image. ie from AssetImage. it will not allow wrap any other widget as imageprovider. how can i get that click?. Is ImageProvider an option? From where i get help for that?